# JavaFX: How to shift elements in a GridPane?

Tags: javafx, gridpane

Let me explain: lets say i have a `GridPane` 10x10 and in position `row = 2 and col = 3` there is a Circle. I have a Button and I want that when the button is pressed, the circle shift to the right 1 step (1 coloumn) so its new position will be `row = 2, col = 4`. The question is: Is it a good idea to create a new class, extending circle and adding to it `int actualRow; var int actualCol;` ? So when I press the button, I will remove the element from `(actualCol, actualRow)` and placed it in `(actualCol+1,  actualRow)` ?

Comment: Why do you want to create a new class ? Any special reason ?

Comment: Because I want to track the position of the circle inside the grid. That's why I though I should save its coordinates. Like it is in a matrix. I also thought (as second solution) that i can make a method that visits all grids cells and when meets the circle it shifts it to the right but I don't know how to do it

Comment: You want to browse through all the children of the GridPane, find Circle and if found, then shift it to the next column ?

Comment: More or less.. but it souns stupid to me. I think having already coordinates of the circle in a `MyCircle` class is better. I don't have to brows the GridPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, storing the `GridPane` row and column inside a class might not be a good idea, as it makes your class tightly bind with the `GridPane` leading to a bad design

Moreover, the approach becomes more complicated when the number of Circles in your gridpane increases, under such scenario, you will have to keep a separate list of all the `MyCircle` objects, which is again an **overhead**

Comment: Are you advising me to make a browse method, search Circles, get their coordinates inside the GridPane and then delete it and make a new one in the right-shifted cell ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am saying. You can always write an algorithm to find the circle from the children and its corresponding row and column index. Just use the same to remove it and then add it to col+1 and row+1 location..